# plugging in terms of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am having some trouble understanding how to plug terms into the following sequence. I was given the following,

$$a_1=1, a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{n}}$$ for all n greater or equal to 1.

Plugging in terms we get the following,

$$a_1=1$$
$$a_2=a_1=1$$
$$a_3=\frac{a_2}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$a_4=\frac{a_3}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$$

How are they getting these terms $a_2,a_3,a_4$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that

$$a_2=\frac{a_1}{\sqrt1}=1$$

$$a_3=\frac{a_2}{\sqrt2}=\frac1{\sqrt2}$$

$$a_4=\frac{a_3}{\sqrt3}=\frac1{\sqrt6}$$

Try to prove by induction that

$$a_{n+1}=\frac1{\sqrt{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots n}}=\frac1{\sqrt{n!}}$$

Comment: why are the $a_1,a_2,a_3$ terms disappearing in the numerator?

Comment: @jh123 Let's start with $a_2$.  Do you understand that $a_2=\frac{a_1}{\sqrt1}$?  From there, what ***is*** $a_1$?  (check definition?)

Comment: why would $a_2$ be equal to that? I thought $a_2=a_1+a_2$?

Comment: Because $a_2$ was defined to be equal to that.  Plug $n=1$ into the definition of the sequence.  Why would $a_2=a_1+a_2$, which would require $a_1=0$?

Comment: @jh123 In the first line, you said $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{\sqrt n}$, did you not?

Comment: yes I did say that

Comment: @jh123 Then if $n=1$, it is true that $a_2=\frac{a_1}{\sqrt1}$, is it not?

Comment: yes that would make sense

Comment: @jh123 And then you said $a_1=1$, so $a_2=\frac{a_1}{\sqrt1}=\frac11=1?$

Comment: yeah that was next

Comment: @jh123 Do you think you can see how $a_3$ was solved for?

Comment: I think what confused me was the $a_1$ term that I thought was $n=1$

Comment: @jh123 Hm, but then you'd have $n=1:$ $$a_{1+1}=\frac{a_1}{\sqrt1}$$I see no problem?

Comment: why is $a_n=1$ in $a_3$

Comment: @jh123 It is not.  If $n=2$, then we get$$a_{2+1}=\frac{a_2}{\sqrt2}$$And we already know what $a_2$ is from earlier.

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art okay I understand it now, thanks very much for your patience

Comment: @jh123 No problem :D

Comment: @jh123 But don't forget to take a peak at the second part of my answer:$$a_{n+1}=\frac1{\sqrt{n!}}$$

Answer (score 2):

They are using the definition.  If you plug in $n=1$ you get $a_2=\frac {a_1}{\sqrt 1}=\frac 11=1.$  Then plug in $n=2$ to get $a_3=\frac {a_2}{\sqrt 2}=\frac 1{\sqrt 2}$ and so on.

Comment: why are the $a_1,a_2,a_3$ terms disappearing in the numerator?

Comment: Because we plug in the value we know for them based on the earlier calculation.

Comment: so if $a_1=1$ then shouldn't $a_2 = \frac{a_1}{\sqrt{2}}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: No, because we were taking $n=1$ and the denominator is $\sqrt n$, not $\sqrt {n+1}$

Answer (score 2):

We have that for $n \in \mathbb Z^+$, $$a_{n+1} = \frac {a _n}{\sqrt {n}} \tag {1}$$

Thus, using the relation $(1)$ successively, we get, $$a_2 = a_{1+1} = \frac {a_1}{\sqrt {1}} = \frac {1}{1} =1 $$ $$a_3 = a_{2+1} = \frac {a_2}{\sqrt {2}} = \frac {1}{\sqrt {2}} $$ $$a_4 = a_{3+1 } = \frac {a_3}{\sqrt {3}} = \frac {1}{\sqrt {2}\times \sqrt {3}} = \frac {1}{\sqrt {6}} $$

Hope it helps.

Comment: why is the $a_1$. $a_2$ $a_3$ terms disappearing in the numerator?